# I am trying to add current logged in user to my zoho chat

Tags: javascript, api

I am trying to get user info auto populated into the chat fields so logged in users don't have to type in their information everytime they want to chat with us. I cant seem to figure out how to make the user fetch call to my zoho chat - can any one help?

Here's zoho JS API call

```
$zoho.salesiq.ready=function()
{
  $zoho.salesiq.visitor.name("<?php echo $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ?>");
  $zoho.salesiq.visitor.email(); 
  $zoho.salesiq.visitor.contactnumber();
}
```

Comment: The [`wp_get_current_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/) returns an object. [Reference the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_current_user/#comment-437) to pull in specific data.

Comment: I am trying to get all those fields when they open the chat while they're logged in, this is all I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Howdy_McGee said, you need to reference the individual data points, not the whole user object.

```
<?php
// Get the user object: username, email, firstname, lastname, displayname, and user ID 
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
// Get other user meta, such as phone number
// (you'll have to check what meta_key you're using for info like this)
$current_user_meta = get_user_meta($current_user->ID);
?>
$zoho.salesiq.ready=function()
{
  $zoho.salesiq.visitor.name("<?php echo $current_user->display_name; ?>");
  $zoho.salesiq.visitor.email("<?php echo $current_user->user_email; ?>"); 
  $zoho.salesiq.visitor.contactnumber("<?php echo $current_user_meta->phone; ?>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works!

Comment: Could you please mark this as the answer in case anyone else searches for something similar? :)